# SQL file convert to KML file

Tags: sql

I want to conert SQL file to KML file. Is there any good way to do this ?

Thanks & BR,
kk

conert SQL file to KML file

Comment: By KML do you mean Keyhole Markup Language? If you do then what do you mean by convert between them? They are completely different languages with different purposes. Can you update your question with an example of a SQL statement and its equivalent in KML?

Comment: Can you show what research you've done so far as possible approaches? It is good etiquette to put effort into your question to show you've attempted something already and don't put all the burden on the answering person.

If you don't know where to begin, then you could ask for good websites or tutorials or documentation where you could learn about those approaches so you can compare them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.